# react-lazy-load-image-component, how to hide until fully loaded?

Tags: reactjs, image, lazy-loading

[image]
[image]

```
import bg from "./img/bg.png";
import react_img from "./logo.svg";

...

  <LazyLoadImage 
    effect='blur'
    src={bg}
    placeholderSrc={react_img}
    alt='stuff'
    height="200px"
    width="200px"
  />
```

Why is it not hiding the main image (src) completely so it can replace the placeholder? Instead it slowly comes down from top to bottom until it loads completely

I dont know why is it this way, but can you make it so it hides it completely until its fully loaded then switch it up?

Comment: can you show the LazyLoadImage implementation?

Comment: It's a React library. https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `react-lazy-load-image-component` [sets the placeholder image as `background-image`](https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component/blob/master/src/components/LazyLoadImage.jsx#L118), and remove it after the image is **fully** loaded. In the meantime, the loading main image **won't be hidden**, so if it's partially loaded/displayed by the browser, it will be displayed along with the placeholder image in its background.

Fortunately, the main image's `onLoad` handler is triggered when the image is **fully** loaded. Hence, one way is to initially set the main image `opacity` to 0 (or `zIndex` to -1) and set it back using the `onload` handler.

```js
const MyImage = () => {

  const [imageStyle, setimageStyle] = useState({ opacity: 0 })

  const ImageLoad = (e) => {
    setimageStyle({})
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <LazyLoadImage
        src={"http://localhost:3080/large_image"}
        placeholderSrc={react_img}
        style={imageStyle}
        onLoad={ImageLoad}
      />
    </div>)
};
```

Alternatively, you can compress the main image's size since it's displayed `200px X 200px` anyways and an image with this resolution should be loaded instantly under normal network conditions.

...Or, consider using a [progressive image format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928444/progressive-jpeg-vs-baseline-jpegs).